# NodeJS arr.splice() not removing from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

Using the following code, I'm supposed to check if the arrays (ai, jq, and rz)
has users with the same 'interest' and if so, remove that user from all arrays.
But it seems that the .splice() method is not be working as I log the arrays and they still contain that user. Any ideas?

Code:

```js
function joinQueue(sid, interests, fn) {
 var exists = false;
 
 interests.forEach(function(interest) {
  interest = interest.toLowerCase();
  getTable(interest.charAt(0), function(table) {
   table.forEach(function(data) {
    if(data.interest == interest && !exists) {
     var aa = 0;
     ai.forEach(function(a) {
      if(a.sid == data.sid) { ai.splice(aa, 1); console.log(ai);}
      aa++;
     });
     var jj = 0;
     jq.forEach(function(j) {
      if(j.sid == data.sid) { jq.splice(jj, 1); console.log(jq); }
      jj++;
     });
     var rr = 0;
     rz.forEach(function(r) {
      if(r.sid == data.sid) { rz.splice(rr, 1); console.log(rz); }
      rr++;
     });
     fn(data);
     exists = true;
    }
   }); 
  });
 });
 if(!exists) {
  interests.forEach(function(interest) {
   interest = interest.toLowerCase();
   getTable(interest.charAt(0), function(table) {
    table.push({'sid': sid, 'interest': interest});
   });
  });
  fn();
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the data passed to joinQueue? sid, interests, fn. The first thing to check is whether the code after `a.sid === data.sid` is ever executed.

Comment: `jq.forEach(function(j, i) { /* do something that adds or remove items in  the array */  }` is typically not a very good idea. Try using [].concat(jq).forEach(d, i) or jq.slice(0). This way, you will loop over a clone of the array.

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you're in the middle of multiple iterations of `jq.forEach()` and you call `jq.splice()` inside the callback?

Comment: @jfriend00 Just realized that, is there a good way to edit an array while looping through a foreach?

Comment: @widged Same question ^

Comment: There are a number of options.  You can use a traditional `for` loop and correct the index when you remove an element.  You can iterate the array backwards with a `for` loop so removing the current element does not mess with the iteration.  You can keep track of the elements to remove in a separate array and then loop backwards over that loop to remove them after the iteration is done.

Comment: @JakeCross code example as answer (untested, more to give an idea)

Comment: If your code doesn't mind, it's easier to traverse the array backwards with a `for` loop because removing the current item you are traversing does not mess with the iteration at all.  In your code you just put in the previous comment you have to do `aa--` after you do `ai.splice(aa, 1);` so your iteration doesn't miss the next element that is now moved down in the to `aa` slot.  I prefer the backwards iteration which doesn't have to do this correction.  `for (var i = jq.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) { code here }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Untested]. It is difficult to establish whether it makes any difference without access to testable code (input data and some other variables are missing).

It is best to avoid to add or remove items to an array as you are looping over it. Best is to loop over a clone of the array rather than the array itself. Try with the code below to see if it makes any difference.

```js
function joinQueue(sid, interests, fn) {
    var exists = false;
 
    interests.forEach(function(interest) {
        interest = interest.toLowerCase();
        getTable(interest.charAt(0), function(table) {
            table.forEach(function(data) {
                if(data.interest == interest && !exists) {
                    var sid = data.sid;
                    var sliceItOff = function(arr) {
                        arr.slice(0).forEach(function(d, i) {
                            // [warning]. if more than one item meets the condition (d.sid == sid), 
                            // then you are likely to remove an item at the wrong index. 
                            // A better approach is to build a new array rather than modify the old one
                            if(d.sid == sid) { arr.splice(i, 1); console.log(arr); }
                        });
                    };
                    sliceItOff(ai);
                    sliceItOff(jq);
                    sliceItOff(rz);
                    fn(data);
                    exists = true;
    }
   }); 
  });
 });
 if(!exists) {
  interests.forEach(function(interest) {
   interest = interest.toLowerCase();
   getTable(interest.charAt(0), function(table) {
    table.push({'sid': sid, 'interest': interest});
   });
  });
  fn();
 }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this have an issue because as soon as you remove an item from the original array, then the index in the cloned array is not the same as the original.  So, if you go to remove the 2nd item, you'll remove the wrong item. It will work the first time, but not the 2nd.  If there's only ever one `id` match per array, this could work, but I think it's a bad pattern because it could easily break.

Comment: It does indeed if more than one item can satisfy (d.sid == sid)

Comment: I would typically use a reduce instead of a forEach for such case. Return a new array with valid elements. Go the immutable way.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a bit safer version that uses a backwards `for` loop traversal to avoid issues when the current item is removed.

```
function joinQueue(sid, interests, fn) {
    var exists = false;

    interests.forEach(function(interest) {
        interest = interest.toLowerCase();
        getTable(interest.charAt(0), function(table) {
            table.forEach(function(data) {
                if(data.interest == interest && !exists) {
                    var sid = data.sid;
                    var sliceItOff = function(arr) {
                        for (var i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                            if(arr[i].sid == sid) { 
                                arr.splice(i, 1); 
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    sliceItOff(ai);
                    sliceItOff(jq);
                    sliceItOff(rz);
                    fn(data);
                    exists = true;
                }
            }); 
        });
    });
    if(!exists) {
        interests.forEach(function(interest) {
            interest = interest.toLowerCase();
            getTable(interest.charAt(0), function(table) {
                table.push({'sid': sid, 'interest': interest});
            });
        });
        fn();
    }
}
```

Comment: A reverse loop is a much better approach, yes :-)